# MySQL Performance: one query using left join vs. multiple queries

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I would like to achieve something like you see on Facebook:

```
- Posting status
- Comment status
- Like status (like for comments not implemented yet)
```

My tables structure is like this :

```
Posts        Users       Comments    Likes
-------      -------     --------    -------
ID           ID          ID          ID
UserID       Username    PostID      PostID
Content                  UserID      UserID
Date                     Content
                         Date
```

So at this time when someone access to the main page the system is going to show the 10 lasts posts. My query uses `LEFT JOIN` on theses tables.

If for example there is 10 posts without any comments and any likes the query will return 10 records.

But for each comment or likes my query will return a new record (row) with some NULL value in the corresponding column.

At the end by simply wanting to retrieve 10 posts my query will return at least 50 rows (if each post has some comments and likes).

I was wondering if that will cause problem in the future. And I was wondering if I should better use multiple queries and parse all the results into an array like:

```
1. Select the 10 last posts
2. Save the IDs into array and all data into global array
3. Parse the array and make a prepared query for the comments something like: 
   SELECT * FROM COMMENTS WHERE PostID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,...) 
4. Save the result into global array
5. Repeat again for the like table
```

I hope my explanation was clear enough :) Thank you

Comment: If I understood you correctly, there is really no choice. You need to get posts that you are interested in and then separately get their details (comments, likes, etc.) If you try to put it all in one query the results would be incorrect. `Posts left join Comments left join Likes` when 1 post has 2 comments and 3 likes would return 6 rows.

Comment: Exactly. I then parse the results into array so at the end I have the same result as if I use 3 differents queries. My concern is more about performance issue. 1 big query or 3 smalls queries

Comment: I don't understand how you can compare two variants when one of them produces incorrect results. At first you need to get correct result and then care about performance. In any case, when it comes to performance you have to measure it on your real data and hardware. Also, quite often network is relatively slow, so it is important to do as much as you can on the server and transfer only the final data. From this point of view it sounds very wrong to me to make one query that returns the same data multiple times (incorrectly) and on top of that have extra step of processing it on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Doing one 50 row query reduces the overhead when communicating with the server, on the other hand it adds processing after the rows are retrieved.

It really depends on the overall solution.
However, unless the application is performance critical with the server being the bottleneck, i would go with 10 result sets - one per row, probably using some class/widget/object to display the post on the page.

Comment: It's just to know if doing 1 query returning 30 rows is better than doing 3 queries returning 10 rows each

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, if I understand correctly your option are:

A) the single mega query that will return a lot of NULL's and repeated values.

[Note: By "all" I mean, all you are interested in]
B) Three queries: One for all posts, one for all comments, and one for all likes (all joined with the users table), and then you can process them into objects or structs or dictionaries with whatever language you are using to query the database.

I would go with the second because It is easier, and the increase in order of magnitude seems benign, and probably even more flexible design wise.

What I would prefer NOT to do is one query per post. That would probably become a problem sooner than later. At least much sooner than A or B.

Comment: Hello. Yes you understood well. For `A` it's exactly that. And I haven't already implemented the option to `Like a comment`. If I continue to use `A` this will keep adding rows in the query result everytime someone has liked a comment.